# Best Method for Adding a Sorted Array to a Reallocated Sorted Array While Sorting the Combined Array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to figure out the best solution for this particular problem.

Here is the rundown of what I am trying to do:

- I have two arrays, A and B.
- B was previously reallocated to make room for the elements in A.
- A is always a fully populated array.
- B always has at least one element.
- Both A and B are already sorted.

I want to add the elements of A to B while keeping the array sorted.

Ex:

```
//Given:
A = [1,3,5]
B = [2,4,6, , , ]

//Desired Result:
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

The fastest way of doing this that I have thought of so far would be:

- Add all of the elements of A to B, would take O(n).
- Sort the combined array, using something like merge sort for O(nlogn).

I'm trying to figure out of there is a way doing this faster than O(nlogn).

Space complexity is not an issue in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need the merge step of a mergesort. The merge step takes two sorted arrays and combines them into one sorted array in O(n) time.

You can save some time copying by starting the merge at the tails of A and B instead of the heads. This would let you perform the merge in place in the storage you've allocated for B instead of needing to merge into a third array and then copy back to B.

Comment: That works perfectly, Thank you for your help! Final implementation was doing the merge step of mergesort in place by starting at the ends of the arrays like you mentioned.